# Send Context of Current Observable Stream to Another Component

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a section of code that allows a user to enter information about some data and then retrieve that data and have it displayed in the UI.

A user enters said data's information and then a modal (a separate component) comes up and asks them to authenticate themselves. All during this time, the initial subscription to the Observable emitted by my `getData()` call is still running.

Suppose I click cancel in my modal and want to cancel the subscription so that when I leave the modal, I can immediately retry? Currently, when I exit, the Observable continues to work until it fails, about 15 seconds later.

Here's a snippet of code:

```
this.dataService.getData(
    id,
    location,
    name
)
.subscribe(() => {
    this.modalService.open('my-modal', // { can I pass the current observable in here? Maybe using this? });
});
```

If I then click `Cancel` on the modal, I'd like to stop the Observable stream. Is there a way to send the context of the current Observable that I am in, and then unsubscribe to it?

Thanks

Comment: This is more of a structure question, and depends 100% on how you've structured your application.

Comment: @Z.Bagley, okay, but is it possible to send the context of the current Observable stream to another service/component?

Comment: For sure, just make sure your services are cyclical i.e. if ServiceA imports ServiceB do NOT have ServiceB import ServiceA. If both services are imported in a parent component you can just pass by reference like any other javascript var for service methods.